# How to refine this sql query with a LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have a problem with the following SQL Query. As you can see, I join some tables (candidate_basic,candidate_lang,province_of_candidate,province,degree_of_candidate), and then I join the result with another table "professional_experience_basic" but, the query return several instances (example: it returns two instances for id_candidate_basic=55, or it returns three instances of id_candidate_basic=59).

My problem is that I only want that the query return 1 instance per id_candidate_basic. That is, the instance with attribute "main_job" with value 1, and if this is not possible, just a null.

I tried to put **AND professional_experience_basic.main_job=1** inside the WHERE clause, but, it remove the instances with **main_job=null**.

I feel that I'm close to the final result but I have spent lots of minutes in this last effort. Does anyone know the solution?
Thanks in advance.

The Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    candidate_basic.id_candidate_basic,
    candidate_lang.town,
    province.name,
    degree_of_candidate.id_degree_of_candidate,professional_experience_basic.main_job

FROM (((((candidate_basic
    INNER JOIN candidate_lang 
    ON candidate_lang.id_candidate_basic=candidate_basic.id_candidate_basic)
    INNER JOIN province_of_candidate
    ON province_of_candidate.id_candidate_basic=candidate_basic.id_candidate_basic)
    INNER JOIN province
    ON province.id_province=province_of_candidate.id_province)
    INNER JOIN degree_of_candidate
    ON degree_of_candidate.id_candidate_basic=candidate_basic.id_candidate_basic)
    LEFT JOIN professional_experience_basic
    ON professional_experience_basic.candidate_id=candidate_basic.id_candidate_basic)

WHERE candidate_basic.candidate_state=2
  AND degree_of_candidate.is_main_degree
  AND candidate_lang.id_website_lang=1
```

The current result:

[image]

The result I want:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change `professional_experience_basic.main_job` to `max(professional_experience_basic.main_job)` in the column list, then:

```
GROUP BY candidate_basic.id_candidate_basic, candidate_lang.town,
          province.name, degree_of_candidate.id_degree_of_candidate
```

Answer (score -1):

First Group your Result

```
... AND candidate_lang.id_website_lang=1
GROUP BY 
    candidate_basic.id_candidate_basic,
    candidate_lang.town,
    province.name,
    degree_of_candidate.id_degree_of_candidate
```

And i think you want the max of main_job, but i dont know.
change select to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    candidate_basic.id_candidate_basic,
    candidate_lang.town,
    province.name,
    degree_of_candidate.id_degree_of_candidate,MAX(professional_experience_basic.main_job)
```

It seems like you want the max here, but i dont know

Comment: Yeah, he'll need MAX or something here. But when doing this kind of GROUP BY, often you don't really care which number you're getting in that last column.